# How to automatic allow in Autostart Manager of ASUS phone?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, asus

I'm having problems with my notifications and it seems that only in ASUS devices occurs. When my app is closed from the `Task Swipe` when I checked in the `App Info` it is `Forced closed` and wondering why in Viber I can still receives notifications. i found out that Viber is already allowed in the `Autostart Manager` so I tried allowing my app and restart my phone after restarting it I can receives notifications now even if its forced closed. I'm wondering is there a way that like in Viber it is already allowed in Asus Autostart Manager.

Thank you in advance!